# fuel ux checkbox select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, bootstrapping, fuelux

I am trying to select all using checkbox but unable to implement it.

```
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2">
  <label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only" type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">2</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox3">
  <label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only" type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">all</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCheckbox').click(function(event) {
    if ($("#myCheckbox").checkbox('isChecked')) {
      $('.checkbox').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
        $('.checkbox').checkbox('check');
      });
    } else {
      $('.checkbox').each(function() {
        $('.checkbox').checkbox('uncheck');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I am using fuelux 3.13, jquery 1.12, bootstarp js 3.13

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

1. You don't need an `each` because the [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) (`$()`) looks for every element that shares the class or id that you specified.
2. The property `checkbox` of FuelUX should be used on the `label`, and not on the `input`.
3. If you want to use FuelUX functions, you should use `checkbox('check')` instead of `prop()` which is JQuery. Given the fact that I am new with web development I would say that both are just the same.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.checkbox.slc-all input').on('change', function() {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')){
         $('.checkbox.slc-chk label').checkbox('check');
       }
       else {
         $('.checkbox.slc-chk label').checkbox('uncheck');
       }
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <div class="checkbox slc-all">
        <label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
            <input class="sr-only" type="checkbox" value="">
            <span class="checkbox-label">Select All</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <div class="checkbox slc-chk">
        <label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
            <input class="sr-only" type="checkbox" value="O1">
             <span class="checkbox-label">O1</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <div class="checkbox slc-chk">
        <label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
            <input class="sr-only" type="checkbox" value="O1">
             <span class="checkbox-label">O1</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

It worked for me. Hopefully, it will also work for you.

Here the example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teshima82/h3rz7f8f/)

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCheckbox3 [type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(' [type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true)
        } else {
            $(' [type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false)
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2">
<label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
<input class="sr-only"  type="checkbox" value="">
<span class="checkbox-label">1</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2">
<label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
<input class="sr-only"  type="checkbox" value="">
<span class="checkbox-label">2</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2">
<label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
<input class="sr-only"  type="checkbox" value="">
<span class="checkbox-label">3</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2">
<label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
<input class="sr-only"  type="checkbox" value="">
<span class="checkbox-label">4</span>
</label>
</div>
   <div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox3">
<label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">
<input class="sr-only"  type="checkbox" value="">
<span class="checkbox-label">all</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(this)` inside `each` instead of `$('.checkbox')` to refer to the current checkbox inside each :

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
   $(this).checkbox('check');  
});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myCheckbox').click(function(event) {  //on click 
        if($("#myCheck").checkbox('isChecked')) { // check select status

            $('.cbk').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                $('.cbk').checkbox('check');  //select all checkboxes with class "cbk"               
            });
        }else{
            $('.cbk').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                $('.cbk').checkbox('uncheck'); //deselect all checkboxes with class "cbk"                       
            });         
        }
    });

});
</script>
    </head>
    <body class="fuelux">
       <div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
  <label class="checkbox-custom cbk" id="myCheck" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only" type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">all</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2">
  <label class="checkbox-custom cbk" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only"  type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">1</span>
  </label>
</div>
        <div class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox3">
  <label class="checkbox-custom cbk" data-initialize="checkbox">
    <input class="sr-only"  type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="checkbox-label">2</span>
  </label>
</div>
```